# The command "\Perp" is in which package?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

```
X \Perp Y \mid Z
```

produces

[image]

But I don't know this command is in which package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txfonts` or `pxfonts`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
% \usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
$X \Perp Y \mid Z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you can declare symbol only for `\Perp`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{txsyc}{bx}{n}
% \DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
% \SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{pxsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Perp}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{121}
\begin{document}
$X \Perp Y \mid Z$

$\bm{X \Perp Y \mid Z}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it also changes the font which is undesirable...Could you fix it?

Comment: @Knt I have updated answer.